# using Thymeleaf (th:each) I couldn't visualize data in the view i get always blank web table

Tags: html, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I want to browse the object returned by the controller and display data in the web using th:each then `th:text ="${object.attribut}"` 
but I get nothing is there a fault in the code bellow

```
<tr>
    <th:block th:each="sb : ${results}">
    <td th:text="${sb.issuenum}"></td>
    <td th:text="${sb.assignee}"></td>
    <td th:text="${sb.summary}"></td>
    <td th:text="${sb.created}"></td>
    <td th:text="${sb.resolutiondate}"></td>
</tr>
```

PS: when I use only `th:text="${sb}"` I get the whole data that means that the object is received by the view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing the `</th:block>` -- and I'm not really sure what you're trying to accomplish.  Do you want a row for each object, or a single row with every object and attribute in a different column -- which appears to be what you have now.

Does this work for you?

```
<tr th:each="sb: ${results}">
    <td th:text="${sb.issuenum}" />
    <td th:text="${sb.assignee}" />
    <td th:text="${sb.summary}" />
    <td th:text="${sb.created}" />
    <td th:text="${sb.resolutiondate}" />
</tr>
```